# Looking for a perl scripts to make addition and pick last number

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a simple perl script to learn Perl. This is the first script I have written using user input. The script needs to get a last numbers after make addition function Any help would be appreciated. Below is what I have so far.

Example user input 9423 and then the scripts were make addition function like below

09+04=13

04+02=06

02+03=05

03+09=12

```
print "Enter 4 Digits Number";#9423
chomp($number = <STDIN>);
```

EDIT

How to pick a last 2 digits numbers so the results are 3652

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @nums = ("9423" =~ /(\d{1})/g);
my $a = $nums[0];
my $b = $nums[1];
my $c = $nums[2];
my $d = $nums[3];
my $ab= $a+$b;
my $bc= $b+$c;
my $cd= $c+$d;
my $da=  $d+$a;

printf "%02d\n%02d\n%02d\n%02d\n", $ab, $bc, $cd, $da;
```

Comment: Your English is making it difficult to understand what you mean. What does `09+04=13` have to do with the input `9423`? What do you mean by `get a last numbers`?

Comment: I make example 09+04=13 is a easy way to show others that i want a scripts to pick last digist numbers. and that is 3.

Comment: And how do you come up with adding `9` to `4`? The first digits are `9,4,2,3`, which makes sense, but the second digits are `4,2,3,9`, which does not make sense, unless you just shifted one digit to the end.

Comment: Its not an easy learning project you picked for yourself. Try using `my @digits = split //, $number` to get the digits. And `my ($last) = $sum =~ /(\d)$/;`

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
    my @nums = ("9423" =~ /(\d{1})/g);
    print "$_\n" for @nums;

Comment: Using the `{1}` quantifier is redundant, since any regex atom matches once by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, here code will output your expected result

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter 4 Digits Number:";#9423
chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);
my @digits = split("", $number);
my @lasts;
# add first digit to the last position
#digits = 94239
$digits[$#digits + 1] = $digits[0];

for(my $i = 0; $i < $#digits; $i++){
    $lasts[$i] = ($digits[$i] + $digits[$i + 1]) % 10;
}
print join "",@lasts,"\n";
```

output after enter number 9423:

```
3652
```

Answer (score 0):

probably easiest way to do it is use a for loop and substring

EDIT (now tested):

```
for my $i (0 .. length($number)-2) {
    print substr($number, $i, 1) + substr($number, $i+1, 1);
}
```

Comment: What you had first was much easier, if you didn't use `length` incorrectly. It should have been `for my $i (0 .. (@data-2)){...}` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a 4 Digit Number: ";
chomp( my $num = <STDIN> );

my @nums = split //, $num;
$nums[ $#nums + 1 ] = $nums[0];

( $nums[$_] + $nums[ $_ + 1 ] ) =~ /(.)$/ and print $1 for 0 .. $#nums - 1;
```

Output after entering 9423:

```
3652
```

Comment: how to make output only last 2 digits numbers that is 3652

Comment: @user2899446 - Show me what you mean. ABCD...?